# How to permutate over columns for each row in a matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, permutation

I have a matrix

```
  A = [1,2;3,4];
```

I would like to generate a new matrix B, which contains all permutations over the columns for each row.

```
 B = [1,2;2,1;3,4;4,3]
```

Is there a one-liner solution?

Answer (score 1):

I could only think of a solution incorporating cell arrays, thus I'm not sure, if that is "efficient" at all. Also, have a look at the [limitations of `perms`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/perms.html?searchHighlight=perms&s_tid=doc_srchtitle#btsl1bk-4).

```matlab
% Input.
A = [1, 2; 3, 4]

% Expected output.
B = [1, 2; 2, 1; 3, 4; 4, 3]

% Calculate output.
C = sortrows(cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) perms(x), mat2cell(A, ones(1, size(A, 1)), 2), 'UniformOutput', false)))

A =
   1   2
   3   4

B =
   1   2
   2   1
   3   4
   4   3

C =
   1   2
   2   1
   3   4
   4   3
```

Comment: Thanks. I am not familiar with cellarray. So I figured out a solution just using perms.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my own question.

```
n = 2; % size of permutations
perm_index = perms(1:n); % index of the matrix to perm
perm_length = size(perm_index,1);
data = [3,4;5,6]; 
data_length = size(data,1);
output_length = perm_length* data_length; 
output = reshape(data(:,perm_index), output_length,n);

%Final output 
output = [4,3;6,5;3,4;5,6]
```

Comment: Nice indexing approach. I didn't follow that route, since you asked for a one-liner solution. (I guess, the one-liner version of this solution would be unreadable. ;-) )

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't find any one-liner solution. Hope this one is simpler enough:

```
 A = [1, 2, 3; 4, 5, 6];
 B = [];
 for i=1:size(A,1)
     B = [B ; perms(A(i, :))];
 end
```

Answer (score -2):

Read about the function *nchoosek*

```
A = [1 2 3 4] ;
B = nchoosek(A,2)
```

Comment: Read the question. It's not the same.

Comment: Why it is not the same?

Comment: See my own answer.